# JScrollPane is not working I used JForm Layout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar, jform

JScrollPane is not working. I created a panel inside it I add JForm Layout. Then I add label and one dynamic panel add JScrollPane in which I add table.

Problem is this JScrollPane is not working properly. it is not showing vertical and horizontal bars, it just reacts like a constant panel with table data.

```
public LedgerPanel_UI() {
    setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("244dlu"),
            FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("250dlu"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("20dlu"),
            FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("fill:207dlu"),
            FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("fill:179dlu"),}));


    style = new Style();

    TableModel_Ledgers model = new TableModel_Ledgers();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    model.setColumnSize(table);
    style.style_Table(table, table.getTableHeader(), false);
    //scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());

    model.setData();
    model.fireTableDataChanged();


    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Add New Customer");


    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    //scrollPane = style.style_JScrollPane(scrollPane, table);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    add(new AddNewLedgerAccountp_UI().init_UI(), "4, 4");
    add(lblNewLabel, "4, 2, center, fill");
    add(scrollPane, "2, 4, 1, 3, fill, fill");

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after some struggle.`table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. This should always display the rulers.

`scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
 scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);`

Comment: It shows correctly if you remove the JForm Layout, right?

Comment: no! not even then showing corectly. if you tell me your email i can send you complete files.

Comment: I just tried it myself and it seem to not show the scrollbar without elements going outside the viewport, even when the VERTICAL_SCOLLBAR_ALWAYS policy is set. You should try to play around with `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));`. This may help you.

Comment: The scrollbar appeared for me as soon as elements in the table was outside the viewport of the scrollpane

Comment: we cannot use setPreferredSize it didnt work in Jform layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollpane= new JScrollPane(table);
add(new AddNewLedgerAccountp_UI().init_UI(), "4, 4");
...
```

It worked for my JTextArea just fine. I don't know if it works with a JTable or your layout though.

EDIT: Works for me with a JTable, too.